# Using column-count and border-style does not work together

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to have a list of items with a bottom line on every item. I am also trying to set the items into 3 columns.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

HTML:

```
<div class="ul_div">
     <ul class="the_ul">
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
        <li>D</li>
        <li>E</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ul_div{
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 3;
    border-style: solid;
}

.the_ul{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li{
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: red;
    border-bottom-radius: 1px;
}
```

And here is a demo of it: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6hpL0hbf/1/)

As you can see, for some reason, the bottom line is not 'stuck' to its respective li item. Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, there is no such thing as `border-bottom-radius`, there's only `border-bottom-left-radius` and `border-bottom-right-radius`, which is logical considering the fact that the radius is applied to the corners of the element.

Now, for your question, you should use `column-break-inside: avoid;` to make sure that the `li` element doesn't get divided into columns, having a part of it into one column and one part into the next column:

```
column-break-inside: avoid;
-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
```

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6hpL0hbf/2/).

And [here](http://trentwalton.com/2012/02/13/css-column-breaks/) is more information about column breaks.

Comment: Hi! Yes, I mistakenly wrote border-bottom-radius, I meant border-bottom-style!  Also, thanks alot for the answer! It solved the issue.

Comment: Also, when I have 3 columns, and 4 items, why does the sorting does the following: http://jsfiddle.net/6hpL0hbf/3/ ? (does 2 | 2 | 0 rather than 2 | 1 | 1)

Comment: As far as I know, the browser decides how to split your content into columns and what goes where. Check this out: http://zomigi.com/blog/deal-breaker-problems-with-css3-multi-columns/

Comment: Thanks for your answeR!

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a width to the li border. You can do this buy adding border-bottom-width: 1px; to your li class. You could instead change you li class to:

```
li{
  border: 0px solid red;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 1px;
}
```

You could also use border-bottom-left-radius and border-bottom-right-radius.